# Append data to top of the JSON file using PHP form

Tags: php

I wanted to append a php from data in JSON file to top.

I used some PHP functions like -

1. array_unshift($array_data, $extra);
2. $array_data = array_reverse($array_data);

Example -

```
<?php  
 $message = '';  
 $error = '';  
 if(isset($_POST["submit"]))  
 {  
      if(empty($_POST["name"]))  
      {  
           $error = "<label class='text-danger'>Enter Name</label>";  
      }  
      else if(empty($_POST["author"]))  
      {  
           $error = "<label class='text-danger'>Enter Author</label>";  
      }  
      else if(empty($_POST["category"]))  
      {  
           $error = "<label class='text-danger'>Enter Thumbnail</label>";  
      }  
      else if(empty($_POST["url"]))  
      {  
           $error = "<label class='text-danger'>Enter URL</label>";  
      }  
      else  
      {  
          if(file_exists('wallpaper.json'))  
          {  
               $current_data = file_get_contents('wallpaper.json');  
               $array_data = json_decode($current_data, true);  
               $extra = array(  
                    'name'               =>     $_POST['name'],  
                    'author'          =>     $_POST["author"],  
                    'category'     =>     $_POST["category"],  
                    'url'     =>     $_POST["url"]  

               );  
               $array_data[] = $extra;  
               //array_unshift($array_data, $extra); // used this as well
               $array_data = array_reverse($array_data);
               $final_data = json_encode($array_data);
               if(file_put_contents('wallpaper.json', $final_data))  
               {  
                    $message = "<label class='text-success'>File Appended Success fully</p>";  
               }  
          }  
          else  
          {  
               $error = 'JSON File not exits';  
          }  
     }  
 }
 ?>
```

Both of these PHP functions, they work perfectly until you add data 2 times but once you add 3rd data or more then it looks like this -

```
[
  {
    "name": "3",
    "author": "3",
    "category": "3",
    "url": "3"
  },
  {
    "name": "1",
    "author": "1",
    "category": "1",
    "url": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "2",
    "author": "2",
    "category": "2",
    "url": "2"
  }
]
```

But it should look like this -

```
[
  {
    "name": "3",
    "author": "3",
    "category": "3",
    "url": "3"
  },
  {
    "name": "2",
    "author": "2",
    "category": "2",
    "url": "2"
  },
  {
    "name": "1",
    "author": "1",
    "category": "1",
    "url": "1"
  }
]
```

Comment: at beggining you have [1] then you insert [2] and after $array_data[] = $extra;  goes to [1][2] and the you reverse array [2][1]. At this moment when you insert a new value you have [2][1][3] and the after reversing [3][1][2]

Comment: @Why would you not simply use `array_unshift()` with this solution?  Am I missing something obvious? @user9157668  Reversing/Flipping the data every time you touch the file is going to make a mess.

Comment: @mickmackusa No array_unshift() also creates same problem

Comment: @user then I cannot reproduce your issue and I will need to vote to close your question.  I have answered and verified that this technique is 100% effective.  If my answer doesn't solve it, then there is something that you are not telling us.  If you are saying that `array_unshift()` doesn't work, then there is likely something flawed about how you have scripted the technique.

Comment: @mickmackusa Sorry but it does not work, i tried it many times, try running my php code instead to check.

Comment: Your php code is not a good way to do this work -- even if you could manage to get it working.  I wouldn't want to help you fix a suboptimal technique -- I only like to show people best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At beggining you have [1] then you insert [2] and after $array_data[] = $extra; goes to [1][2] and the you reverse array [2][1]. At this moment when you insert a new value you have [2][1][3] and the after reversing [3][1][2] the solution would be reversing before insert extra:

test.php:

```
    <?php
      if(file_exists('wallpaper.json'))
      {

           $current_data = file_get_contents('wallpaper.json');
           $array_data = json_decode($current_data, true);
                          $extra = array(
                               'name'    =>     $_REQUEST['name'],
                               'author'  =>     $_REQUEST["author"],
                               'category'=>     $_REQUEST["category"],
                               'url'     =>     $_REQUEST["url"]

                          );
                          echo $extra['name'];
           $array_data = array_reverse($array_data);
           $array_data[] = $extra;
           $array_data = array_reverse($array_data);
           $final_data = json_encode($array_data);
           if(file_put_contents('wallpaper.json', $final_data))
           {
                $message = "<label class='text-success'>File Appended Success fully</p>";
           }
      }
      ?>
```

to run I used to pass parameters:

```
http://localhost/test.php?name=4&author=4&category=4&url=4
```

Comment: No it does not work it appends like this ```[
  {
    "name": "3",
    "author": "3",
    "category": "3",
    "url": "3"
  },
  {
    "name": "1",
    "author": "1",
    "category": "1",
    "url": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "2",
    "author": "2",
    "category": "2",
    "url": "2"
  }
]```

Comment: I inserted all code and rerun and the order is like you want, please compare with your code maybe there is something missing

Comment: It fine that it works but it seems "overkill" to use array_reverse() two times.

Answer (score 0):

```
$posted[] = $_POST; 
$current_data = file_get_contents('wallpaper.json');
$decoded = json_decode($current_data,true);

//You merge together posted array values with the current array
//that is in the current file (after decoding the json)
//$posted is first part of the array because you start to merge from that
//array
$new_arr = array_merge($posted, $decoded); 

//Encode the new array into JSON and save it
$encoded_json = json_encode($new_arr,);
file_put_contents('wallpaper.json', $encoded_json);
```

Comment: It puts Null in file

Comment: I don't understand why. It worked here. If you have your original code the diff is basically that you use $array_data = array_merge($extra, $array_data); instead of $array_data = array_reverse($array_data);

Answer (score 0):

First, don't push the `$_POST` data into its own subarray.  It is already in the correct structure to call `array_unshift()` directly on it.  In other words, you don't need to index it -- unshift will apply the `0` key for you.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/VXde6))

```
$fileContents = '[{"name":"B1","author":"B2","category":"B3","url":"B4"},{"name":"A1","author":"A2","category":"A3","url":"A4"}]';

$array = json_decode($fileContents, true);

$_POST = [
    'name' => 'C1',
    'author' => 'C2',
    'category' => 'C3',
    'url' => 'C4',
];

array_unshift($array, $_POST);
echo json_encode($array);
```

Output:

```
[{"name":"C1","author":"C2","category":"C3","url":"C4"},{"name":"B1","author":"B2","category":"B3","url":"B4"},{"name":"A1","author":"A2","category":"A3","url":"A4"}]
```

---

Secondly, I don't support the notion of building this json file if there is any way that you can avoid it.  I mean, as you your file size increases, your server will have to work harder and harder and harder to parse the json, manipulate it, re-encode it every time you want to make a change.

I might recommend that you restructure your file to be a txt file which is a collection of json strings -- all of which are separately written on each line.  This way you don't have to unpack and repack your data every time, you just prepend the new json string to the file and walk away.  *Caveat, this will fail if the data that you are storing contains newline characters -- I don't know if your project might receive such data.

---

p.s. If you are not a ultra-purist developer and your incoming data is as tame as it looks from your post, you can hack at the json string and lighten the workload like this:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/BCBs3))

```
$newJson = json_encode($_POST);

if ($fileContents) {
    $fileContents = substr_replace($fileContents, $newJson . ',', 1, 0);
} else {
    $fileContent = '[' . $newJson . ']';
}
echo $fileContents;
```

Comment: Actually this JSON file is used by my wallpaper app to read wallpapers, so